# Trying to get iOS AddressBook Contact Picture

Tags: image, swift, ios8, xcode6, addressbook

I have a piece of code I am struggling with.  I am trying to retrieve the thumbnail picture of a contact.  I know this may not exist, but so I am trying to check for nil before it gets assigned.  Somehow Xcode still tries to upwrap the nil and my program keeps crashing with the message:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is my code snippet:

```
 if UIImage(data: ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(allpeople[i], kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail).takeRetainedValue() as NSData) != nil {

            pic = UIImage(data: ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(allpeople[i], kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail).takeRetainedValue() as NSData)!

        }
```

allPeople is defined as:

```
 var allpeople: [ABRecordRef] = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook)?.takeRetainedValue() as [ABRecordRef]
```

I don't get it, is there another way to check for nil without the program crashing?

Comment: Try the code step by step, check that `kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail).takeRetainedValue() as NSData` isn't returning nil as well.

Comment: Also, it's tricky to test this without more of the code, `allpeople` for instance

Comment: I've edited it.  var allpeople: [ABRecordRef] = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook)?.takeRetainedValue() as [ABRecordRef]

Comment: I'm able to pull first name, last name, notes, record ID, Phone Numbers etc...the Picture is what I seem to be having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured this out.  Here is what I did to fix my problem.  Seems like the first line was where I screwed up, ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat itself was returning nil before all the other stuff in a case where a profile image is not set.  So it helped me to break my line into smaller chunks like so:

```
var pic: UIImage = UIImage(named: "default-pic.png")!
var picTemp1 = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(allpeople[i], kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail)?
        if picTemp1 == nil{
            println("NIL FOUND")
        }
        else{
            println("PICTURE FOUND")
            var picTemp2: NSObject? = Unmanaged<NSObject>.fromOpaque(picTemp1!.toOpaque()).takeRetainedValue()
            if picTemp2 != nil {
                pic = UIImage(data: picTemp2! as NSData)!
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let thumbnailData = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(allpeople[i], kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail).takeRetainedValue()
if thumbnailData != nil {
    pic = UIImage(data: thumbnailData)
}
```

Comment: I was just about to post my solution that I just figured this out by breaking that 1 line into multiple lines.  It seems that first line was where I screwed up, ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat itself was returning nil before all the other stuff in a case where a profile image is not set